# Access to the path is denied in Windows Store application

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I create Windows Store application. In MainPage.xaml.cs I want to get data from xml file, but I get error message on line:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(filename).
```

> UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled by user code
>
> Access to the path 'C:\Events Project\events.xml' is denied.

Any advice is appreciated.

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
private EventMan man = new EventMan();

public MainPage()    
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.LoadEvents();
}

private void LoadEvents()
{
    this.Events = man.GetAllEvents(@"C:\Events Project\events.xml");
}
```

EventMan.cs

```
public List<Event> GetAllEvents(string filename)
{
    if (filename == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("filename");
    }

    XDocument document = XDocument.Load(filename);

    ...    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only access certain locations with Windows Store apps by default, as explained here:

[File access and permissions in Windows Store apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967755.aspx#locations_all_apps_can_access)

You can put the file in your app's [AppData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj553522.aspx) folder. Then you can use the [`ApplicationData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.aspx) class to freely access the file from there...

```
var file = await ApplictionData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("events.xml");
```